# Spotify/iTunes Full window app

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I'm currently working on an application using Visual studio 2010.. And was trying to create an interface like that of iTunes and Spotify, where it's a full window app, with custom window controls. Could anyone point me in the direction as how to do this?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pszm4txuxt400tt/spotify.PNG

Comment: do you mean a custom window ? try looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978444/how-can-i-style-the-border-and-title-bar-of-a-window-in-wpf/9978718#9978718 or other similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using WPF for a simple attractive set of controls which you can edit as required.
You can set you main windows mode on the On Load event to be fullscreen or maximised.
Google WPF tutorials if you want to learn more about using the controls available.

Comment: Thanks people, found out exactly how to do it, using DragMove(); methods etc