# Add a UserControl in/over titlebar in Window

Tags: wpf, user-controls, styles, window, titlebar

In WPF, I want to add a userControl in/over titlebar in Window, like this:

[image]

The Red part is that UserControl, and the Green part is titlebar.

Now I hope to get some suggestions from you. Need to extend the Window class or just customize the style of the Window? It's better to provide source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by implementing your own title bar.
In order to do so set your window style to none:

```
WindowStyle="None"
```

This will mean that the window will have no control box (minimize, maximize, and close buttons) and you will need to implement your own.

You can take a look at the following links to get you started:

http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/16/how-to-create-a-custom-window-in-wpf/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140267/Create-Custom-Windows-in-WPF-with-Ease

http://www.kirupa.com/blend_wpf/custom_wpf_windows.htm

[How can I style the border and title bar of a window in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978444/how-can-i-style-the-border-and-title-bar-of-a-window-in-wpf)

Good luck

Comment: like http://www.kirupa.com/blend_wpf/custom_wpf_windows.htm, will emerge some problem, such as MinWidth or MinHeight is invalid, in other words, you can make the size of window small than the min size.

Comment: @SubmarineX it also uses blend which you don't have to do, but the other links may be more helpful :)

Comment: is there a way to keep the window style to normal AND have controls on it at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to sub-class `Window`. You can adjust the style for `Window`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969824.aspx.