# WPF popup title bar coming alway in white background in Windows 10

Tags: wpf, windows-10, messagebox

Anyone have any idea how to change the messagebox title bar color to the default in windows 10 (looking for the default like in windows 8 or older). At present it is coming as white.

Answer (score 0):

I am also searching for a solution. But I'm afraid that at the moment only UWP supports this feature. Not WPF.

What you could do is hiding the tilte bar and making a custom one.
Similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9978757/3319147