# How to change background color title bar?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to change window title bar background color in wpf? I know I can create my own template for window but it's to complicated and I in that case I have to create my own minimize, maximize and close buttons instead of using default ones. All I want is change background color, nothing more.
So, is there any simple solution to just change background color and everythig else remains the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing WPF title bar background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283006/changing-wpf-title-bar-background-color)

Comment: As far as I know the title bar is not in the client area so you can't without doing the work you didn't want to.