# Main Window title bar color change in wpf

Tags: wpf

I want the color of title bar to be changed from green to red in wpf.
How can I do it??

Like this -

[[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing WPF title bar background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283006/changing-wpf-title-bar-background-color)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Title bar is not a client area and hence is not available for editing as such.
You can though set `WindowStyle="None"` and then add a custom border around your window.

Make sure you add Close Maximize and Minimize buttons to it.

And if you are using `.net 4.5` [WindowChrome](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsdk/2010/08/25/experiments-with-windowchrome/) can be useful as well