# Change title bar color of window in WPF.

Tags: wpf, titlebar

I new for WPF application. My requirement is to change the color of the title bar to blue color. I search a lot for the same thing but I failed to find out the way to achieve it. 
Thanks.

Comment: See the accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283006/changing-wpf-title-bar-background-color

Comment: I did with Package MahApps.Metro. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I style the border and title bar of a window in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978444/how-can-i-style-the-border-and-title-bar-of-a-window-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use your own custom chrome. Can use community projects like MahApps.Metro to help you with this.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the WindowStyle="None" and then build your own window as this question [How to create custom window chrome in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792275/how-to-create-custom-window-chrome-in-wpf) suggests.