# How to change Main window title bar background color in WPF

Tags: wpf

I want to Change background color of my main window title bar

I tried by creating custom title bar and attaching events to close, maximize and minimize, is there any other way to change/customize main window title bar ?

Comment: It's very hard to answer your question because you didn't provide any code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing WPF title bar background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283006/changing-wpf-title-bar-background-color)

Comment: in that i can see that they created custom title bar and added commands to close and minimize. but, i don`t want to create events . i want to use default window events and want to change the background color

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978444/how-can-i-style-the-border-and-title-bar-of-a-window-in-wpf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using .net 4.5, you can use [WindowChrome](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.shell.windowchrome.aspx) for this.

> You can customize a window border by setting the Window.WindowStyle
>   property to None or by using the WindowChrome class.
>
> **WindowStyle.None** One way to customize the appearance of a WPF
>   application window is to set the Window.WindowStyle property to None.
>   This removes the non-client frame from the window and leaves only the
>   client area, to which you can apply a custom style. However, when the
>   non-client frame is removed, you also lose the system features and
>   behaviors that it provides, such as caption buttons and window
>   resizing. Another side effect is that the window will cover the
>   Windows taskbar when it is maximized. Setting WindowStyle.None enables
>   you to create a completely custom application, but also requires that
>   you implement custom logic in your application to emulate standard
>   window behavior.
>
> **WindowChrome** To customize a window while retaining its standard
>   functionality, you can use the WindowChrome class. The WindowChrome
>   class separates the functionality of the window frame from the
>   visuals, and lets you control the boundary between the client and
>   non-client areas of your application window. The WindowChrome class
>   lets you put WPF content in the window frame by extending the client
>   area to cover the non-client area. At the same time, it retains system
>   behaviors through two invisible areas; the resize border and caption
>   areas.

Here is some help on [Experiments with WindowChrome](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsdk/2010/08/25/experiments-with-windowchrome/)

Comment: Thank you :)  that`s great explaination

Comment: I used Mah apps :)